# jQuery responsive banner auto resize images and content to fit space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, banner, flexslider

I want to create custom banner or download one.

The banner has following requirement,

1. I could add images and text in this banner.
2. On each slide you can add multiple images and text, for an example slide one has two images and text on sides, then slide two has three images and text on the sides.
3. IMPORTANT – if the images are small thumbnails the text should fill the blank areas or around the image. The banner should be responsive to the element inside (could be an div).  If the image is big the text should go underneath the 
   image or on the side.
4. slides left or right
5. left and right navigation button, as well pagination

Example:  http://www.bbc.co.uk - main banner at the top

I had  a look on the internet i tried the following:

flexslider - very good, meet all the requirements apart from point 3. but dont know how to make it responsive.

orbit slider - good but flexslider it easier to style.

Note: this banner will not be used on mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you didn't get any answers because there's no such thing as a perfect finished solution. It's not difficult to change any of the mentioned sliders and make them responsive **IF** you know some css. I'd suggest that, depending on how many of these works you want to do, you give it a try. You can find good free tutorials online.

I found this one plugin though, worth a try: http://marktyrrell.com/labs/blueberry/

And some more: http://webdesignledger.com/resources/8-responsive-jquery-slider-plugins

Comment: Thanks for the links, yea i guess you right. in end i chose flexislider. but blueberry looks good.